# Como puedo utilizar el valor de una variable de un JFrame en otro JFrame?

Tags: java, poo, jframe, get, null

Estoy haciendo un aplicativo donde se tiene que iniciar sesión con un código, con el código obtengo un el nombre del usuario desde una BD MySQL. En el Primer jFrame (Login) logro obtener el nombre del usuario, sin embargo al tratar de invocar ese valor en un segundo jFrame (Vist_Operario), el valor de la variable me aparece nula y no se a que se debe. dejo una parte del código.

[image: Parte donde tengo una variable con el valor que quiero y la meto en un método getter]

[image: jFrame (Vist_Operario) donde quiero utilizar el valor obtenido del jFrame anterior]

[image: Aquí se muestra el resultado del código, donde primero me da el valor pero en el jFrame me devuelve un "null"]

Comment: cuando invoques el jframe debes enviar la variable.

Answer (score 1):

Pude solucionar el problema inicializando la variable resultNombreUser como statica.

```
static String resulNombreUser
```